# Signal processing : future values prediction

Tags: statistics, regression, signal-processing, interpolation, spline

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function.

**Do you have some references (books or online resource) about techniques that allow to predict $f(x_{n+1})$, knowing $f(x_0), ..., f(x_n)$ ?**

I'd like to find a panorama of such methods  (in signal processing or statistical methods, regression, moving average, or interpolation methods or anything else).

[image]

---

Example: can *spline interpolation* be used for future value prediction, given past values $f(x_0), ..., f(x_n)$?
[I don't really think so because the spline on $[x_{n-1}, x_n]$ is just using information about $f(x_{n-1})$, $f(x_{n})$, $f'(x_{n-1})$, $f'(x_{n})$ and **not** older values. So using this spline to predict future values would only take two points in consideration and *not* the $n+1$ past values. Please correct if I'm wrong.]

Comment: You can look in almost every book about machine learning, data analytics. You can use regression, stochastic diffrerential equation. But in all cases prediction will be not exact, but in some range of values.

Comment: Linear predictor, Kalman filter, and particle filter are just a few.

Comment: Thanks @Maerorek and AnonSubmitter for these ideas. There are indeed many, many methods, each of them suited for some precise cases. Do you know where I could find a global panorama, in order to *see the big picture* ?

Answer (score 1):

The book "Elements of Statistical Learning" should give you a good overview.

You can get it from one of the author's websites: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/